# Javascript Array lookup efficiency: associative vs. stored associative?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

I've been reading, and they're saying that associative arrays won't give you the same efficiency as arrays.  An associative array can look things up in O(N) time, where an array can look things up in O(1).

Here's my question: which one would be more efficient in terms of looking up values quickly and not hogging too much memory?

Associative:

```
var myVars=new Array(); 
myVars['test1'] = a;
myVars['test2'] = b;
myVars['test3'] = c;
... (up to 200+ values)

echo myVars['test2'];
```

Stored Associative:

```
var myVars=new Array(); 
var TEST1 = 1;
var TEST2 = 2;
var TEST3 = 3;
... (up to 200+ values)

myVars[TEST1] = a;
myVars[TEST2] = b;
myVars[TEST3] = c;
... (up to 200+ values)

echo myVars[TEST2];
```

Comment: FWIW there's no such thing as an [associative array](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX9) in Javascript... just an object with a similar access process.

Comment: Test the performance yourself: http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays

Comment: Or this one: http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array-perf

Comment: @Felix Your test is not realistic to his _specific_ question.  See my test.  It disproves yours.  Also, your object and array access testing is not well-thought out.  You aren't comparing apples to apples.

Comment: and another test http://jsben.ch/#/Y9jDP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, the first usage of `Array` is wrong. Although it is *possible* to do it, it does not mean you should. You are "abusing" the fact that arrays are objects too. This can lead to unexpected behaviour, e.g. although you add 200 values, `myVars.length` will be `0`.

Don't use a JavaScript array as associative array. Use plain objects for that:

```
var myVars = {}; 
myVars['test1'] = a;
myVars['test2'] = b;
myVars['test3'] = c;
```

Second, in JavaScript there is no real difference between the two (objects and arrays). Arrays extend objects and add some behaviour, but they are still objects. The elements are stored as properties of the array.

You can find more information in the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4):

> Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1. (...)

So both:

```
var obj = {'answer': 42};
obj['answer'];
```

and

```
var arr = [42];
arr[0];
```

have the same access time<sup>†</sup>, which is definitely **not** `O(n)`.

†: It is better to say *should* have. Apparently this varies in different implementations.

---

Apart from that, your second example is horrible to maintain. If you assign numbers to variables, why not use the numbers directly?

```
var myVars = []; 
myVars[0] = a;
myVars[1] = b;
myVars[2] = c;
```

---

**Update:**

More importantly: You have to choose the right data structure for your needs and this is not only determined by the access time of a single element, but also:

- Are the keys consecutive numbers or arbitrary strings/numbers?
- Do you have to access all (i.e. loop over all) elements of the collection?

Numerical arrays (arrays) and associative arrays (or hash tables/maps (objects in JS)) provide different solutions for different problems.

Comment: Are you *sure* it is wrong?  I'm not a JavaScript programmer, but my understanding is that a JavaScript `Array` is a type of `Object`, and therefore can be used like any other object.  Doing so is confusing, but not technically incorrect.

Comment: @btilly: It is wrong because it is confusing. I don't mean technically wrong. E.g. if you assign values this way, `arr.length` will still be `0`. Will clarify my answer...

Comment: @btilly Until you want to iterate through your hash and end up with all of Array's methods.  Granted you can get around this as well but unnecessary work when there is a cleaner and much more common place container.

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained better.  

I have more than one of these storage devices, and having a lookup table for each one would have been fairly annoying.  Ideally, I would much rather see myVars['test1'] in my code than myVars[23], especially when I have several myVars to look at.

Comment: I agree with update.  However, here is a performance test: http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays

Comment: @howdoicodethis: Then use objects. If there is a difference than it should not be that huge. You can always run tests later and see whether you gain anything by changing from or to arrays.

Comment: @FelixKling, I think your jsperf is too limited. Array in JavaScript is a hashtable, which is slightly more expensive to query than an Object, but almost all modern browsers have expedited read times. There is no significant performance difference between accessing properties in Array vs Object; however, edit/delete/add operations have different computational costs.

Answer (score 3):

I posit that the present responses do not fully consider more practical use cases. I created [this jsperf to demonstrate](http://jsperf.com/performance-of-array-vs-object). While @Felix's [jsperf demonstrates lookup speed](http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays/edit), it's not performed on sufficiently large objects to be really useful. I think 10,000 simple properties is more reasonable. Further, you need to randomly select keys in the sequence to read, modify, delete and create to truly demonstrate the performance differences between the two types.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, whoever they are, feel free to ignore them.

Every decent implementation of every decent scripting language, including JavaScript, will give you associative arrays that are either O(log(n)) access time, or else O(1) average access time, O(n) worst case (which you almost never hit).  Either way in practice a lookup is fast.

Arrays have O(1) guaranteed access time, which is incredibly fast.  But in some scripting languages (eg PHP) there isn't even a native array type provided.  They just use associative arrays for both.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have proper arrays either, they're faked.  Lookups in current array implementations take the same time as object property lookups.

Comment: @Alnitak: JavaScript arrays support shift.  That suggests to me that there are 2 different lookup mechanisms under the hood, because supporting shift with an associative array would be painful.

Comment: it _is_ painful - most implementations have to renumber all of the existing keys whenever you do that!

Comment: see http://jsperf.com/pop-vs-shift-on-a-array/6 (not mine) for comparison of pop vs shift.  Preprending is 1000x slower on older browsers.  Only Chrome and IE9.0 have O(1) type performance on arrays.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: [test it out yourself](http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays).**

***Update:** After some back-and-forth with Felix, it appears that array access is usually faster than both associative arrays and objects. This is not always the case, notably in Chrome.  In Chrome 11 on Ubuntu 11, arrays are faster.  In Chrome 11 on Mac OS 10.6 there is no notable difference between them.*

*These tests did not measure manipulation, only reading.*

Comment: There seems to be something with strings containing numbers as object properties in Chrome. If you use "normal" strings, both show the same performance: http://jsperf.com/object-vs-array-perf

Comment: @LeviMorrison: You have to be careful. You are still using an array `[]` as "associative array". You should use an object instead. From the specification I assume that whenever a property is set on an array the property is checked whether it is a number or not, which creates an overhead. Compare the results when using an object: http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays/3

Comment: @Felix: To be honest, you are the one who needs to be careful.  I understand your concern, but ultimately I am testing what the author asked.  If he's willing to swap to true objects, then so am I.  I answer the question being asked. :)

Comment: @Felix: Also, I did compare the results on http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays/3  and in Firefox, we get a large performance difference in favor of arrays.

Comment: @LeviMorrison: I guess here we can see again what differences there are in browser implementations. Yes you are right, you are answering the question literally. But I assume that the OP does not know that arrays should not be used this way. And only showing that one way is slower will make him believe he cannot have something like associative arrays in JS. Imo it is better to clarify this misunderstanding. But in any case, your test cases are interesting.

Comment: @Felix: See http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays/4 to further expand on your idea.  Even as true objects, they are slower than their array counterparts.

Comment: @Felix: A mega test: http://jsperf.com/javascript-associative-vs-non-associative-arrays Let's both test this in multiple browsers.  I really want to know now, lol.

Comment: Thank you for the test!  What's funny is that according to my browser, array access is the SLOWEST, but according to Chrome and Firefox 4, it's the fastest.  I guess I can't win either way :)

Comment: @user727853 Run the tests a few times in several browsers yourself.  Also, this post answers your question and backs it up with proof.

Comment: @Felix: I'm running Linux on an iMac and that may make a difference. What OS are you on?  My tests are always the same: Array access is ALWAYS faster.

Comment: @LeviMorrison: MacBook Pro with Mac OS 10.6. At least in Chrome, array access is not always faster.

Comment: I'm on XP Firefox 3.6.x as well as Mac 10.4.x Firefox 3.6.x ... Array access is slower.  It's fine, haha, can't win them all.

Comment: I wonder why the ones without numbers are so much slower in Chrome 11.